# Fetching dropdown options via AJAX, does not work when characters like æøå

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, encoding, utf-8

My name is Dan and i have seen problems with UTF encoding earlier, read posts related to this kind of issues here on stackoverflow, tried the solutions that you guys have posted but i have to say i am stuck.

Ok, what i am making is a set of dropdowns that get populated via AJAX (jQuery) and PHP when tha values are changed.

1. ALL files are saved as UTF-8
2. The index.php file where all gets displayed have meta tag charset=utf-8

**The PHP scripts reads directories and outputs list options based on folder names:**

```
$fylke = $_GET['fylke'];
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('../pdfs/'.$fylke) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
$kommune = $fileInfo->getFilename();

echo "<option name='kommune' value='".$kommune."'>".$kommune."</option>";
}
```

**The Javascript runs functions based on listbox changes:**

```
function getKommune() {
    $.get("get.php",
  {
    fylke: $("#fylke").val()
  },
  function(data){
    $('#kommune').html(data);
    $('#kommune').attr('disabled', false);
  $('#kommune').prepend('<option selected="selected" value="---">---</option>');
  });
}
```

All folders and filenames with no special characters lists just fine.
When it comes to a special character (æøå) the listbox do not update with folders or files.

I must say i am a beginner at coding, help is much appreciated.
Here is a link to the non working project: http://www.tbds.no/pdfdl/

**Thanks for the great help.**

**I want to share the script with you if you want it, but implement security! : [www.dan-levi.no/playground/pdfdown/files.zip](http://www.dan-levi.no/playground/pdfdown/files.zip)**

Comment: Your script is probably vulnerable to [path traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack). You should fix that immediately by applying `basename` on `$_GET['fylke']` before using the value in the path.

Comment: Thank you Gumbo, i will apply this. Can you think of any solution to my problem with the characters? It is something about this utf encoding i havent learned apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the basic problem you're having is that your system's filenames aren't in UTF-8, and you're pulling data directly from the filesystem and pushing it to the browser saying "this is UTF-8".

I think you need three changes:

First, at the top of `get.php` and at the top of `index.php`, do this before you have any output:

```
<?php
// Set utf-8 in the header, not just as a meta tag
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

If you don't do this, then the browser treats your `get.php` output as `ISO-8859-1`, since the scrap of html you spit out with `get.php` doesn't have a `meta` tag to tell it otherwise.

Second, in the bit that you quoted from `get.php`, you should pass the incoming `fylke` parameter through `utf8_decode` and pass anything going back to the browser through `utf8_encode`:

```
$fylke = utf8_decode($_GET['fylke']);
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('../pdfs/'.basename($fylke)) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    $kommune = utf8_encode($fileInfo->getFilename());
    echo "<option name='kommune' value='".$kommune."'>".$kommune."</option>";
}
```

Third, in `index.php`, apply `utf8_encode` to filenames before sending them to the browser.

Comment: Thank you Daniel Martin, your answer got most of my problems out of the way. Actually, now the listboxes works as intended, but the download link does not work.

When hovering the link i get the correct path. But when i click it it becomes like this: http://www.tbds.no/pdfdl/pdfs/%C3%98stfold/R%C3%B8mskog/1.pdf

I have tried the script locally and that worked just fine. I have set utf8_decode to all paramteres and pass them back by using utf8_encode, this was the solution for listboxes. The actual download link does not work.

Comment: Ok i tried to move this to another domain and it worked right out of the box after i stripped it for all encode and decode functions. This proves that the server i was running this code at works differently from the one i am running it at now. The working example is here: http://dan-levi.no/playground/pdfdown

A pdf file is in here: First listbox choose Østfold, Second choose Rømskog. Thanks again for your help!